# How to calculate the MaxClient value in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to set an optimum value for MaxClient in apache for my production server. 
What are the parameters that I should consider while calculating this value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [Apache Performance Tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html#hardware) guide.

Quote

```
"You can, and should, control the MaxClients setting so that your server does not spawn   
so many children it starts swapping. This procedure for doing this is simple: determine 
the size of your average Apache process, by looking at your process list via a tool such 
as top, and divide this into your total available memory, leaving some room for other 
processes."
```

Answer (score 12):

Complementing @Sameer answer, I read a lot of this theme and what I do is this:

1. Get the Apache process average size:

   ```
   server# ps -ylC apache2 --sort:rss

   S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI   RSS    SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
   S    33  6233 25895  0  80   0  7432 72802 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2
   S    33  6250 25895  0  80   0  7432 72802 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2
   S    33  6278 25895  0  80   0  7432 72802 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2  
   S    33  6280 25895  0  80   0  7432 72802 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2 
   S    33  6577 25895  0  80   0  7432 72802 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2
   S    33  6299 25895  0  80   0  7772 72891 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2
   S    33  6295 25895  0  80   0  7776 72891 poll_s ?        00:00:00 apache2
   ```

   **As you can see in the SZ column my Apache process size is about 73 MB**
2. Make the following formula

   ```
   MaxClients: ((Total_Memory)(1024)(MB) - Other_processes_memory) / 73
   ```

   For Example: I have 16 GB RAM, I might leave free 2 GB for any other processes

   ```
   MaxClients: ((16*1024) - 2048) / 73
   MaxClient: 196
   ```

This is what I use & my server is going great.

You have to consider that my Apache processes are a little heavy, so you could have processes about 50 MB or less.

Regards,

Your SZ is slightly the same for all Apache processes.
In my case I have values between 23 and 212 Mb

[image]

What value should I use in your formula ?

By the way in Apache 2.4 MaxClients has been renamed to MaxRequestWorkers.
Is your formula still valid for this new parameter ?

Regards

Comment: Not necessarily a global solution as there are many many other factors and programming to consider.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from tachomi is not overly comprehensive, but seems like a reasonable way to begin estimating.

In addition to that, this will help you to figure out some of the resources Apache is currently consuming:

```
ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{count = NR;} END {print count " Apache processes";}'
ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{sum += $1;} END {print sum " MB total mem usage";}'
ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{avg += ($1 - avg) / NR;} END {print avg " MB avg mem usage";}'
```

Comment: To improve accuracy, you should insert a `grep -v grep` after the `ps` command. Otherwise awk will also count the grep process.